# Deletar CSS aplicado ao Irmãos de objeto clicado com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como poderia `resetar` um CSS aplicado com `Javascript` via Clique em elemento? Tenho uma tabela cujos `tr` e `td` são criados dinamicamente e uma tabela `table` é criado direto no `HTML` estático, os `td` naturalmente não possuem `CSS` este `CSS` é aplicado quando o `td` é clicado porem desejo deletar o `CSS` dos outros `td` irmãos do `td` clicado.

Código da Tabela HTML:

```
<table id="palavras">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Cadillac</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Cachorro</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Camaro</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Código do Javascript resposavel por adicionar o `CSS` (fucnionando) e desaplicar ao irmãos do elemento clicado:

```
$('body').on('click', ' #palavras td', function (e){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#333');
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#fff');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

```
$('body').on('click', ' #palavras td', function (e){
    $('#palavras td').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
    })

    $(this).css('background-color', '#333');

});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.